# Finding, and replacing, a very specific pattern with regexprep

Tags: matlab, regexp-replace

The string below is from a .csv file. I need to replace the comma decimal with a point decimal, i.e. "92,3245" -> "92.3245". Everything else must be unchanged.

```
str = 'Data,2016-03-11,12:25:55;660,"100","0","92,3245","145","0","0"'
```

I tried

```
pat = ',*(?=\d)';
str = regexprep(str,pat,'.');
```

But then

```
>> str =
   Data.2016-03-11.12:25:55;660,"100","0","92.3245","145","0","0"
```

I then tried

```
pat = ',*(?=\d*")';
str = regexprep(s,pat,'.');
```

But then

```
>> str =
   Data,2016-03-11,12:25:55;660."100"."0"."92.3245"."145"."0"."0"
```

My though was that `',*(?=\d*")'` matches any comma that is followed by any number of digits, followed by a quotation mark, however this does not seem to be the case.

All help is much appreciated!

For clarity: desired result is

```
str = 'Data,2016-03-11,12:25:55;660,"100","0","92.3245","145","0","0"'
```

Comment: I suggest playing around on a site like [regex101](https://regex101.com) to refine your patterns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're on the right track. The most important thing I see that you need to pay attention to is the difference between `*` and `+`. From [the documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/regular-expressions.html), `expr*` matches `expr` *zero or more* times consecutively, where `expr+` matches `expr` *one or more* times consecutively.

So with `',*(?=\d)'` you are telling MATLAB's regex engine that you want to match everything in `str` that has a trailing number, because `,` doesn't need to be matched. The engine is at least smart enough to *not* do this, otherwise you'd end up with something like:

```
Data..2.0.1.6-.0.3-.1.1..1.2:.2.5:.5.5;.6.6.0,".1.0.0",".0",".9.2..3.2.4.5",".1.4.5",".0",".0"
```

If we swap the quantifier, we get the following:

```
str = 'Data,2016-03-11,12:25:55;660,"100","0","92,3245","145","0","0"';

expression = ',+(?=\d)';
replacement = '.';
newstr = regexprep(str, expression, replacement)
```

Which returns:

```
newstr =

Data.2016-03-11.12:25:55;660,"100","0","92.3245","145","0","0"
```

Now, you correctly noticed that your pattern wasn't specific enough and refined it to say that you want to find a comma that's followed by some number of digits *and* a quotation mark. But again, with `*` you are telling the regex engine to find and replace everything in `str` with a trailing single digit (you have no quantifier after `\d`) and quote, because it doesn't have to match a comma.

If we again swap the quantifiers, we get the following:

```
str = 'Data,2016-03-11,12:25:55;660,"100","0","92,3245","145","0","0"';

expression = ',+(?=\d+")';
replacement = '.';
newstr = regexprep(str, expression, replacement)
```

Which returns:

```
newstr =

Data,2016-03-11,12:25:55;660,"100","0","92.3245","145","0","0"
```

Yay!

It's worth noting that this regex will not fix large numbers, where you'd see a thousands separator and decimal separator.

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks for the thorough explaination @excaza, I really appreciate your help!